# Git works except push "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Tags: git, push

Why can I not push? How can I resolve or troubleshoot this?

I can clone, fetch, and pull just fine from my Bit Bucket repos, but when I try to push I get the following error. It only happens on my new computer. I can still push with my old one. I am using putty for ssh. I have the same experience with all of my remote repos. Everything works fine from my old computer, so I know the repos themselves should be fine.

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 3.66 KiB | 3.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have more information, but I'm not sure which other parts are relevant.

Comment: Are you using ssh or https remote urls (run `git remote -v` to find out). Maybe you need to set up an ssh key for the new computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally rebooted and then push worked with no changes. I am using ssh. I set up the keys using putty gen. Everything was working except push. I could clone, fetch, pull, but not push. I shut down. Waited a day or two. Booted back up, and now it all works... When in doubt, reboot.